# github pages wont propagate after being set up with my username

Tags: git, github

https://github.com/m-n-/m-n-.github.io

Why won't this page load at: http://m-n-.github.io ?

It's been significantly over the 10 minutes set up period. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: It appears to be a bug from GitHub side. I suspect issue with dashes in your username. Did you try to contact the support team or to open a ticket?

Comment: Try to go to https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages, go to the end of the page and click on "Contact a human". You will probably have a more relevant answer to your question

Comment: @Antwane that is exactly what I was thinking... seems a bit dumb if that is the case.

Comment: I found an interesting discussion, probably related to your problem. https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2211 Are you using Linux, Mac OS or Windows (or maybe another system)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reach this URL http://m-n-.github.io/ as expected with a computer under Linux, Mac OS or Windows with Chrome/Chromium, but not with Firefox under Linux. The source of the issue is probably the different implementations of sockets in these systems, as explained here: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2211

Unfortunately, the best move here is to change your username. The issue is not located in GitHub server but in the client browsers (and the OS they run in), and I am not sure you should expect a patch in the Linux kernel :/

Comment: Yeah, as you mentioned this appears to be an issue with Linux on Firefox, as I am able to see it with Chrome on Linux. Seems quite unfortunate that this issue exists. I guess the only solution is to change my username. ;_;